# When to bind a service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm developing an application which have a main activity with 5 tabs. In other words, that main activity contains a framelayout that can be replaced with 5 different fragments. Furthermore, the application can navigate to others activities from that main activity, but the user will have to return to that main activity to keep navigating through the application. On the other hand, I have a started service that is started on the application's onCreate method, this service gets some data from our API, and some of that data is used for the next fragments/activities: - 2 out of 5 fragments that may be replaced in the main activity. - Some of the others activities that may be started from that main activity.

So I was wondering about the best way to bind to that service (to get that data). I've thought 3 options:

1) Each fragment/activity that needs the data of the service binds to it on its own onStart method, and unbinds the service on its onStop. So each fragment/activity would be totally independent from the other fragments/activities.

2) The activities that needs the data from the services and the main activity (instead of the fragments) binds to the service. So the service will not be bound/unbound when navigating through the tabs, but will be bound even if the user is in a fragment that is not required.

3) Create a singleton on the application's onCreate method that binds to the service, so the fragments/activities that needs some data from the service would use that singleton instead of binding/unbindig to the service.

I have currently developed the first option, but I keep thinking about which option is the best. What do you think? May you lend me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use an application scoped singleton in these cases. Fragments/Activities can just access the service whenever they need to without having to worry about stopping and starting anything. I have an example [here](https://github.com/KEOpenSource/SharedService).